# How to get location within the camera use in Swift 3/4?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

I am coming to this problem where I have a camera and a map view where all I want to do is get the location if the photo is taken using the app that you can access the user's location at the moment the image is captured and extend UIImage to include a property for location and save this location at the same time onto the map view or tableView that you save the image when the picture is taken using the phone's camera. Thank you for any help.

Here is my code. (Camera Controller)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultLbl: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func CamBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        if !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            return
        }

        let cameraPicker = UIImagePickerController()
        cameraPicker.delegate = self
        cameraPicker.sourceType = .camera
        cameraPicker.allowsEditing = false
        MapViewController.location.requestLocation()
        guard let userLocation = MapViewController.location.location else {return}
        present(cameraPicker, animated: true)
    }


    @IBAction func LibBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        present(picker, animated: true)
    }
}
   extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true)
        resultLbl.text = "Analyzing Image..."
        guard let image = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage else {
            return
        }

}
```

MapViewController

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000
    var location: CLLocationManager!
    let nearbyRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        location = CLLocationManager()
        location!.delegate = self
        location.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        location.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        location.startUpdatingLocation()

        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            location!.startUpdatingLocation()
        } else {
            location!.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        mapView.showsUserLocation = false
    }


    func location(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch status {
        case .notDetermined:
            print("Not Determined")
        case .restricted:
            print("Restricted")
        case .denied:
            print("Denied")
        case .authorizedAlways:
            print("AuthorizedAlways")
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("AuthorizedWhenInUse")
        location!.startUpdatingLocation()
        }  
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("Failed to initialize Map: ", error.description)
    }

}
```

Comment: So what is your problem, what is not working? Please explain what is the issue you are facing not just what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Well, @DavidPasztor the problem is, I am getting the user location, But It is not quite getting it when user is taking a picture. All I want to do is, when the camera is open, get the users location at the same time onto the map view or tableView, When is captured

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the user's location at the time of the photo, you need to request a location update when the user takes a photo and not just start location updates in your other `ViewController`. You can request a one time location update using `CLLocationManager().requestLocation()`, but be aware that this is an asynchronous call, so the user might finish taking the photo by the time this returns.

To mitigate this issue, you can either use `PromiseKit` to get your function to return only when the asynchronous method finished or you can use `CLLocationManagerDelegate` `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])` method and update the picture/MapView as soon as the location update is received.

In `MapViewController` change `var location: CLLocationManager!` to `static var location = CLLocationManager()`, update your `MapViewController` class accordingly to work with `location` being a type property and not an implicitly unwrapped instance property. Then in `CameraController` change your function like so:

```
@IBAction func CamBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        if !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            return
        }

        let cameraPicker = UIImagePickerController()
        cameraPicker.delegate = self
        cameraPicker.sourceType = .camera
        cameraPicker.allowsEditing = false
        MapViewController.location.requestLocation()
        guard let userLocation = MapViewController.location.location else {return}
        present(cameraPicker, animated: true)
    }
```

This is not a full example, you still need to add `userLocation` to your image/MapView, but you should be able to figure that part out by yourself. Also, with this implementation `requestLocation()` is not guaranteed to return by the time you check its value, so I'd rather use `PromiseKit`'s `CLLocationManager.promise()` function, which only returns once the location is updated.